# Cannot deploy ASP.NET MVC with write permissions for specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I've been trying to create a feature of error logging for the application so that, when enabled in `web.config`, an error log text file would be created in the server path `~/ErrorLogs` folder.

However, despite trying to follow instructions on a link below, I still have a permission denied message when testing this on the IIS Server (which is version 10):

http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/SettingFolderPermissionsOnWebPublish.aspx

Here's my project target wpp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<Target Name="SetupCustomAcls" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">  
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
      <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\ErrorLogs</Path>
      <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
      <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
      <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
    </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" AfterTargets="AddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="ErrorLogsSetAclParam">
      <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
      <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
      <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\ErrorLogs$</Match>
      <Description>Add write permission to the ErrorLogs folder.</Description>
      <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/ErrorLogs</DefaultValue>
      <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/ErrorLogs</Value>
      <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
      <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
      <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
    </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Can anyone advise on any additional steps I need to take so that these permissions are set automatically when I'm deploying the web application?

Comment: could you please share deailed error message snapshot and sample code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi @Panchal, I can do if when I get back from work today. The deal is, I purposely had another error created so I could fire my error writing routine. The focus error, however, says that asp.net needs permissions to write to the folder. So I'm not entirely sure what logging like this will help accomplish exactly.

Comment: Big thing is, it's really annoying to have to manually alter the permissions of this one folder every time I web deploy so that error writing can begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement this requirement you need to follow below steps:

- Select application in visual studio and right click and select "Unload project".
- add below code in .csproj file.

Note: make sure you added folder proper path.

```
 <Target Name="SetupCustomAcls" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
    <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\test</Path>
    <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
    <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
    <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
  </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
    <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\bin</Path>
    <setAclUser>iusr</setAclUser>
    <setAclAccess>Read</setAclAccess>
    <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
    <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclUser;setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
  </MsDeploySourceManifest>
</ItemGroup>
```

```
<Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" AfterTargets="AddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems">
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="testSetAclParam">
    <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
    <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
    <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\test$</Match>
    <Description>Add write permission to the Elmah folder.</Description>
    <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/test</DefaultValue>
    <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/test</Value>
    <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
    <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
    <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
  </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
  <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="BinSetAclParam">
    <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
    <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
    <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\Bin$</Match>
    <Description>Add read permission to the bin folder.</Description>
    <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/bin</DefaultValue>
    <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/bin</Value>
    <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
    <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
    <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
  </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
</ItemGroup>
```

- after adding code save the file and reload the project.
- select project and right click and select "publish".
- On the Publish page, click the icon labeled IIS, FTP, etc.
- In the Publish Method list box, select Web Deploy:
  [image]

[image]

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: I just noticed that I'm using the FTP deploy method. Do I HAVE to use the Web Deploy method for this to work?

Comment: yes, you need to use web deploy method to work your code. FTP will upload files to FTP server (can be any OS that handles FTP).

Comment: I have my server's IP, but its DNS is local to its own network, not to the WWW. I notice this local DNS to its network, atm.affirmhealthcenter.com, is not recognized. How would I get around this?

Comment: OK, sorry. I figured that out. But right now I'm using MySQL as the database. It seems that Web Deploy only supports OLE DB/SQL Server???

Comment: Just got this to work. Thanks so much for your help!